# Django - Delete file from amazon S3

Tags: python, django, file, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a problem where deleting an object form the admin won't delete the file associated with it. after some research I decided to implement a post_delete in the model.
For some reason I am not able to make the s3 delete the file, even after searching numerous guides and snippets, maybe someone here knows.
I use django 1.5 and boto.
Heres my code for the model:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from fileservice.formatChecker import ContentTypeRestrictedFileField
from south.modelsinspector import add_introspection_rules
import os
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from django.core.files.storage import default_storage as storage
add_introspection_rules([
    (
        [ContentTypeRestrictedFileField], # Class(es) these apply to
        [],         # Positional arguments (not used)
        {           # Keyword argument
            "content_types": ["content_types", {}],
            "max_upload_size": ["max_upload_size", {}]
        },
    ),
], ["^fileservice\.formatChecker\.ContentTypeRestrictedFileField"])

class Contentfile(models.Model):
    content = ContentTypeRestrictedFileField(upload_to='uploads/', content_types=['video/mp4', 'application/pdf', 'image/gif', 'image/jpeg', 'image/png'],max_upload_size=5242880,blank=True, null=True, help_text='Upload a file to add it to the content the app displayes')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, editable=False)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, editable=False)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    file_type = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    published = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    file_owner = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='Contentfiles')

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["title"]

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        file_name = os.path.basename(self.content.name)
        self.file_type = file_name.split('.')[-1]
        self.title = file_name.split('.')[0]
        self.published = True
        super(Contentfile, self).save(*args, **kwargs)



@receiver(models.signals.post_delete, sender=Contentfile)
def auto_delete_file_on_delete(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    """Deletes file from filesystem
    when corresponding `MediaFile` object is deleted.
    """
    if instance.content:
        if os.path.isfile(storage.open(instance.content.path)):
            os.remove(storage.open(instance.content.path))

@receiver(models.signals.pre_save, sender=Contentfile)
def auto_delete_file_on_change(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    """Deletes file from filesystem
    when corresponding `MediaFile` object is changed.
    """
    if not instance.pk:
        return False

    try:
        old_file = Contentfile.objects.get(pk=instance.pk).content
    except Conentfile.DoesNotExist:
        return False

    new_file = instance.content
    if not old_file == new_file:
        if os.path.isfile(storage.open(old_file.path)):
            os.remove(storage.open(old_file.path))
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

It is MUCH safer to do post_delete. If something goes wrong you will start missing S3 files and you wont notice it because your DB records are intact. post_delete will be safer since it is less likely that S3 delete operation would fail after you have deleted your db record. Furthermore even if file delete fails you will be left with a bunch of unreferenced S3 file which are harmless and can be easily cleaned up.

```
@receiver(models.signals.post_delete, sender=Picture)
def remove_file_from_s3(sender, instance, using, **kwargs):
    instance.img.delete(save=False)
```

Comment: David, could you elaborate the "cleaning unreferenced S3 files" part of your answer? How would you go about removing files from S3 which do not have a reference in the database, while keeping the referenced files?

Comment: @David Dehghan... I'm also interested in the last part, how to easily delete unreferenced S3 files?

Comment: I am not aware of any special magic for deleting unreferenced S3 files. You would have to run a batch job that dumps the ID of all your S3 files and then run a query to get your DB file IDs and compare the 2 lists. For now we have just ignored this problem. It is possible that we have orphaned items in S3 but in our case the cost is cheap enough that we can ignore it.

Answer (score 11):

You need to call [FieldFile's](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.fields.files.FieldFile) `delete()` method to remove the file in S3. In your case, add a [`pre_delete`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/signals/#pre-delete) signal where you call it:

```
@receiver(models.signals.pre_delete, sender=ContentFile)
def remove_file_from_s3(sender, instance, using):
    instance.content.delete(save=False)
```

Comment: Im a bit reluctant to add a pre_delete method, because for example if anything goes wrong with the delete, I remain with the opposite situation where I have a file represented in that database but is deleted from the server

Comment: Heh, I misread your post, thought it had a pre_delete handler. Whatever floats your boat I guess.

Comment: Anyways, that's besides the point. Worked like a charm and I accept your'e answer. Thank you very much!

Comment: Is it possible to add an example of how this works in the model? It is a bit unclear as to where that instance comes from, where the signal function is etc

Comment: Added a complete signal handler example.

Comment: Due to my previous comment, I have changed the accepted answer since it better reflects what I ended up using

Answer (score 7):

Try [django-cleanup](https://github.com/un1t/django-cleanup), it automatically invokes delete method on FileField when you remove model.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me by deleting files both in DB and in AWS S3.

```
from django.db import models
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.views import generic
from project.models import ContentFile
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin,UserPassesTestMixin

class DeleteFileView(LoginRequiredMixin,UserPassesTestMixin,generic.DeleteView):
   model = ContentFile
   template_name = 'file-delete.html'
   success_url = 'redirect-to'

   #Check if the owner of the file is the one trying to delete a file
   def test_func(self):
      obj = self.get_object()
      if obj.user == self.request.user:
        return True
      return False

    #This code does magic for S3 file deletion 
    @receiver(models.signals.pre_delete, sender=ContentFile)
    def remove_file_from_s3(sender, instance, using, **kwargs):
       instance.image_file.delete(save=False)
```

I am using `pre_delete` you can check the [django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/signals/#pre-delete).File reference deletion in DB is done by DeleteView, I hope this helps someone